# Find the total number of connection made to azure service plan from last 24HR/12HR/1HR using powershell

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Context: Want to find the total number of connection has been made to Azure Service Plan, under which my application is running. Want to automate it, is there any way ?

So far I have wrote code to connect to the azure with the following code,

```
function connectionMenthod($AzureUserName,$AzureP,$AzureTenantID,$AzureSubscriptionID) {
    $username = $AzureUserName;
    $password = ConvertTo-SecureString $AzureP -AsPlainText -Force;
    $creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList ($username, $password);
    Connect-AzAccount -Credential $creds -Tenant $AzureTenantID 
}

function upgradeNFREnvironment () {
    $AzureTenantID = "<Azure_tenant_id>"
    $AzureSubscriptionID = "<Azure_Subscription_Id>"
    $AzureUserName = "<User_Name>"
    $AzureP = "<Password>"
    connectionMenthod $AzureUserName $AzureP $AzureTenantID $AzureSubscriptionID
}

upgradeNFREnvironment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Want to find the total number of connection has been made to Azure
> Service Plan, under which my application is running. Want to automate
> it, is there any way ?

After reading  through multiple Azure documentations & blogs understood that currently  using PowerShell we don't have any way to pull the total number of established connections of a particular webapp over a  period of time.

Using Diagnostics & solve problems blade in the portal , we can check summary about the Total Number of TCP connections established for a particular instance under the webapp over a period of time as show in below

[image]

You can refer this documentation for more information about [TCP connections in App service](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2018/03/01/Deep-Dive-into-TCP-Connections-in-App-Service-Diagnostics.html) & this reference  [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40807309/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-tcp-connection-statuses-for-an-azure-app-service-app) thread as well.